# transforming string a to string b

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

Given  2 strings `A` and `B`, you have to transform `A` to `B` in two operations:

- `delete(i, len)`: delete len chars starting from `i` from `A` (you can delete no chars)
- `insert(i, str)`: insert a string str in `A` at `i`-th index (you can insert an empty string)

You have to minimize the number of character deleted by the delete operation.

Constraints:

- insert can be applied only after delete
- delete and insert can be applied only once

Example1:

```
A = aabcdef  
B = aaefg
```

Answer: `delete(2, 3)`; `insert(4, "g")`. All in all, 3 chars are deleted which is the best we can do.

Example2:

```
A = aaaaa  
B = a
```

We just need to delete 4 chars

I thought of `O(n^3)` and `O(n^2)` solution, but I have been told that there is a better solution than that.

Comment: Perhaps it is late, but I am confused by the requirements. If the main performance characteristic is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of operations, isn't there always an `O(1)` solution: delete the entire string A followed by insertion of the entire string B?

Comment: @angelatlarge you have to minimize the number of chars deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got an `O(n)` solution. It is done in several steps.

First of all, let as reformulate the problem. We have to remove a substring from `A` and a substring from `B` so that what left would be equal. And we want to remove as short substring from `A` as possbile. Note that your insert operation is in fact equivalent to same delete operation on `B`.

**Lemma.** If you strip off equal prefixes or suffixes from both `A` and `B`, it wouldn't affect the optimal solution. Leave proof to a reader :)

Now, extract the maximum common suffix and prefix of `A` and `B`, so `A=XA*Y`, `B=XB*Y`, where `X` and `Y` are substrings. If `A*` or `B*` is empty, we got a simple degenerate case. If not, let us make a new notation `A<-A*`, `B<-B*`.

At this point `first(A) != first(B)` and `last(A) != last(B)`. Otherwise, we should have included a common symbol to prefix or suffix at previous step:

```
A = a1 A' a2
B = b1 B' b2
```

where `a1 = first(A)`, `a2 = last(A)`, `b1 = first(B)`, `b2 = last(B)` and `A'` and `B'` are substrings of `A` and `B`. Here `a1 != b1`, `a2 != b2`.

To make `A` and `B` equal we have to remove the first symbol from one of the string and the last symbol from the other. You have two cases here. Let us consider only one, where you remove first symbol from `A` and last symbol from `B`.

All you have to do now is to remove as less symbols from the beginning of `A` as possible, so that the suffix left would be equal to some prefix of `B`. For that, you should construct a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) of string `A` and go through all prefixes of `B` to check whether they are presented in suffix tree. Pick the largest then. Once you're done, you have the largest string `C`, which is the suffix of `A` and the prefix of `B`:

```
A = PC
B = CS
```

Remove `P` from `A` and `S` from `B` and you're done.

For the original `A` and `B` (without common parts removed) we have:

```
A = XPCY
B = XCSY
```

In the original formulation of the problem, `P` is deleted and `S` is inserted.

Suffix tree may be constructed in `O(n)`. Stripping off the gretest common suffix and prefix at the first step takes `O(n)`. Suffix tree traversal is done in `O(n)`.